# EF Code First "String or binary would be truncated" when running Update-Database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My Migration looks like this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.TargetTable", "Table1Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddForeignKey("dbo.TargetTable", "Table1Id", "dbo.Table1", "Id");

        AddColumn("dbo.TargetTable", "Table2Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddForeignKey("dbo.TargetTable", "Table2Id", "dbo.Table2", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.TargetTable", "Table1Id", "dbo.Table1", "Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.TargetTable", "Table1Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

        DropForeignKey("dbo.TargetTable", "Table2Id", "dbo.Table2", "Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.TargetTable", "Table2Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

    }
```

and when I run "Update-Database" I'm getting the error:
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

I'm not creating any tables, just adding two columns to an existing table. So I am unsure where this error could be coming from. I'm not manipulating any string or binary columns. Any help would be much appreciated.

*Edit*

The table is empty. It has no rows, that's why the columns are fine being non-nullable.

The Model:

```
 public class TargetTable
{
    //This column already exists.
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }

    public int Table2Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting not nullable fields into existing table. If table contains rows, it will cause error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the types on the column and foreign key are the same type

Comment: They are, the "Id" columns are integers.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table?